# Checkbox in Github Markdown table not updating

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I can create checkbox in Markdown table

```
| Title | Status       |
|-------|--------------|
| Test  | <li>[ ]</li> |
```

The checkbox can be displayed and can be checked.
However, it doesn't persist i.e. when we refresh the page, the checks disappear.

Is there a way to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is not possible. According to the documentation, GitHub only supports checkboxes in Markdown lists. There are number of factors which contribute to this.

Note that the spec for the [Task list items extension](https://github.github.com/gfm/#task-list-items-extension-) states:

> This spec does not define how the checkbox elements are interacted
> with: in practice, implementors are free to render the checkboxes as
> disabled or inmutable elements, or they may dynamically handle dynamic
> interactions (i.e. checking, unchecking) in the final rendered
> document.

And I'm not aware of any documentation from GitHub which explains how GitHub handles this outside of the spec.

Presumably, for GitHub to save the change of state to the checkbox, after you check the box, a JavaScript request would need to be sent back to the server, the server would then need to modify the box from `[ ]` to `[x]` and save a new version of the file to your git repo. It is not clear to me whether GitHub actually does this. If they don't, then saving a change in state is not possible under any circumstances.

However, assuming they do provide a mechanism for saving a change in state, the server would likely expect the typical syntax for checkboxes, which would look something like `-[ ] description` at the beginning of a line (or preceded by whitespace only). However, you are not using that syntax, so the server wouldn't be able to reasonable figure out what change it needs to make to update the checkbox and it would fail silently.

Of course, GitHub's Markdown [table](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-) syntax does not allow block-level items within its table cells, so you can't use the Markdown list syntax and are falling back to raw HTML. Actually I'm surprised that even gets converted to a checkbox. In other words, you appear to have tricked GitHub into rendering a checkbox in a location they don't support checkboxes. It is more likely that a future update will cause the checkbox to not be rendered at all than for any future update to save the updated state of your checkbox.